# How to properly change letter color using a for-loop in Java

Tags: java, for-loop

I used `substring` and `charAt` to add a colored background:

```
String word = "ungabunga";
for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++){
 word = word.substring(0,i) + "\033[0;97;41m" + word.charAt(i) + "\033[0m" + word.substring(i+1);
}
System.out.println(word);
```

This outputs

```
[0;97;41m[0;97;41m[0;97;41m[0;97;41m[0;97;41m[0;97;41m[0;97;41mungabunga
```

with only the first bracket colored red instead of ungabunga colored entirely in red.

Comment: You're inserting control codes inside other control codes.

Comment: Think about what happens to `word`. After the 1st iteration the content would e `"\033[0;97;41mu\033[0mngabunga"`. Now you advance to index 1, i.e. the 2nd character. What's that character in `word` now? (Hint: it should be `3`). You probably want to use a separate string or even a `StringBuilder` and _append_ the results of each iteration to it (i.e. the character and the color control sequence). - However, you seem to always set the same color so why not insert the control sequence just once and include the first 7 characters in between?

Answer (score 0):

You should not change the string that is also the input for your for-loop. Moreover, control codes like this can be wrapped around the whole String you want to change.

If you intend to make the word "ungabunga" red, just insert the control statement for red in front and the reset statement at the end.

```java
String word = "ungabunga";
word = "\033[0;97;41m" + word + "\033[0m";
System.out.println(word);
```

Or if you want to highlight just a specific part of the text:

```java
String word = "ungabunga";
int from = 1;
int to = 7;
word = word.substring(0,from) + "\033[0;97;41m" + word.substring(from,to) + "\033[0m" + word.substring(to);
System.out.println(word);
```

Answer (score 0):

You were replacing your initial String `word` each iteration. You can use another String, `coloredWord` for instance, that will be used to display the word with a red background for *i-th* letter:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
        String word = "ungabunga";
        for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++){
            String coloredWord = word.substring(0,i) + "\u001B[41m" + word.charAt(i) + "\033[0m" + word.substring(i+1);
            System.out.println(coloredWord);
        }
    }
```

There's no need to loop over each letter if you want the word to have a red background entirely:

```
System.out.println("\u001B[41mungabunga\033[0m");
```